# Joining tables using concat column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tables I want to join using SQL.

[image]

Since they did not have a common column I used

```
SELECT NEW_ID = CONCAT ('0',table1.ID)
```

Now that I have the new column with matching data in both tables, how do I join both tables? Is there any way to use the NEW_ID column as a temporary column so that I do not have to alter table 1?

Comment: Please tag correct DBMS. MySQL <> sql-server

Comment: Please add more data and also tag one rdbms(either sqlserver or mysql)..I believe implicit conversion will occur in case of sqlserver if one table id is int

Comment: Implicit conversion *will* occur which means `CONCAT` isn't needed. It will result in the *wrong* value anyway, if the ID is greater than 10. A `cast(ID as int)` on the text column would be better, to ensure the proper conversion occurs.

Comment: Performance will suffer whether you use `CONCAT` or let SQL Server use implicit conversions because the server won't be able to use any indexes on the converted column. It's better to *fix* the second table so that ID is an integer or add another column with the ID as a number

Comment: PS `CONCAT` only works because the integer is implicitly converted to string before concatenation. `FORMAT(ID,'0#')` would return the correct result but performance would still suffer

Answer (score 1):

In your case, suitable. of course in terms of performance it is not the best solution ( compare fields with diffrent types)

```
Select * 
From Table1 As t1 inner join Table2 as t2
     ON t1.ID = CAST(t2.ID AS INT)
```

Comment: SQL Server will perform this cast implicitly. There's no need to use any function. Performance will suffer though

Answer (score -2):

You Can Just give the Concrete Expression in the Join.You Don't have to add a new Column For that. Like this

```
SELECT
  *
   FROM Table1 A
       INNER JOIN Table2 B
          ON RIGHT('00'+A.Id,2) = RIGHT('00'+B.Id,2)
```

Comment: @FranklinHuynh no it didn't unless you never expect more than 10 rows

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh that's even worse

Comment: But Better compared to what's he is doing right now

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh not at all. This is another CONCAT using a different function (+), only with a hack to cover it up for values less than 100. And you convert *both* columns when only one needed converting. Check the comments to the question

Answer (score -2):

Different ways, here's one:

```
 ;WITH CTE AS 
 (
 SELECT NEW_ID = CONCAT ('0',table1.ID) FROM TableA
 )

 SELECT * FROM CTE AS C INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON C.New_ID = B.ID
```

Comment: You don't need to do this much. You can use the Expression is the Where Clause. Using a CTE or Inner QUery is Just a Waster of Effort here

Comment: Both answers are wrong, because the original query is wrong. Both will fail if ID is greater than 9

Comment: That's a matter of taste. I like using CTE's when I want to refer to an alias, especially when a lot of aliased are needed. I never said this was a must, this is simply an option, as valid as other options.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh and both answers fail in both. The execution plan will probably be the same. Performance will be bad in both cases.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh There is no performance decrease whatsoever!

Comment: in the case of fewer records, but when there is a huge amount of records, duplicating the entire result set just in order to accommodate an expression which is not even useful is Waste of effort.  This is Just a sample problem in the Question

Comment: It's syntactical, no duplication. With 5 billion rows, there is no performance decrease either. If you don't believe me, test it on your machine and get back to me with the test results.  :)